# GlobalSettings.onError で捕らえられない例外の処理方法

Tags: scala, playframework

play framework (2.3) で、例外の補足を総合的にとらえる方法は無いでしょうか？

通常のリクエスト処理中の例外は GlobalSettings.onError で捕らえられますが、

```
def action = Action{
 Ok.chunked(Enumerator.outputStream(o => csvWrite(o)) >>> Enumerator.eof)
}
def csvWrite(o:OutputStream) = throw new Exception()
```

のように Enumerator.outputStream などを使って非同期で書き出ししたい場合など、その内部(上の例だとcsvWrite)で例外が起こった場合、コンソールにdebugレベルでエラーが記述されるだけです。

やりたいことは、例外をキャッチしてエラーレベルでスタックトレース付きのログを吐きたい（そしてアラートメールなどを出したい）のです。もちろん個別に try-catch して処理することはできますが、どこかで忘れそう。なので、アプリケーション全体で一つ（あるいはいくつか）設定すれば大丈夫みたいな仕組みを探しているのですが、ありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

あまり自信ないし、おそらくこのパターンで救えない酷い例もある

(例 https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3707 )

と思いますが、一つ考慮すべき点としては、play関係なくScala自体の `ExecutionContext` が、catchされなかった例外を処理する機構を持っているので、そこを明示的に設定した `ExecutionContext` を使う、とかでしょうか？

デフォルトでは、`printStackTrace` するだけの実装が使われるはずです。

- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.scala#L175
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.scala#L137